# Jbilling + Ruby

Tags: java, ruby, billing

Are there ready solutions (gems, plugins, libraries, etc) for integration ruby (rails) applications and jbilling?

I didn't find even api client for ruby.

I need someone to share his experience with integration. Jbilling has web-service (SOAP ,Java RMI, Burlap) but there is no specific gem for easy accessing and editing data via API.

JRuby 1.6.0 was Released yesterday.

Lines from jbilling  manual "All of the API classes are located in the jbilling_api.jar file located in your jBilling
distribution.
The API also makes use of several third-party libraries, such as the Log4j library and
Commons Logging, which provides a powerful logging infrastructure; Spring, which
handles configuration and remoting; CXF, a SOAP library; and Hessian, for
Hessian/Burlap support. You'll therefore need to provide the log4j.jar, commons-
logging.jar and spring.jar files in your class path, if your project does not already
include them.
"

Is that good practice to include so many jars in jruby rails application ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try making your app run on JRuby and using the Java libraries directly. We did an experimental branch of our own app for a similar reason and found some useful projects in the process:

- https://github.com/nicksieger/warbler/
- https://github.com/calavera/trinidad

In the end we didn't go for JRuby, for various reasons that weren't necessarily of a technical nature.

Comment: what about api ? Is jbilling api not enough for working with it  from another application ?

Comment: Oh, I don't really know jbilling, I just wanted to point out that it's easy to use jars directly from JRuby. Without looking at the API, I often found `httparty` (https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty) great for rolling my own little API clients.

Comment: thanks for reply anyway . using jars directtly is interesting idea

Comment: Sure, the main selling point of JRuby for many is to be able to mix and match Java and Ruby libraries as they please. I don't think having 4 jars in your class path would qualify as excessive, especially if you later deploy your app as a war to an application server.

Comment: Can you tell me one more thing. I have jbilling_api.jar and also jbilling-remote-beans.xml with configuration of api client. Can you tell me where should I put jars and xml config and what should I do to make it works. I don't exactly understand how can put it together in rails aplication

Comment: It's not that I don't want to help you, but this is probably the right time to send you over to the JRuby Wiki: https://github.com/jruby/jruby/wiki

Answer (score 1):

What version of jB are you using? You could use [this](https://github.com/emilc/jbilling-api-samples) project as an example to do your integration.

You can also build such a project from scratch using wsdl2 java utility. Typically, you can access jBilling wsdl at localhost:8080/jbilling/services/jbilling?wsdl assuming jb is running on your local at port 8080.